# This ActiveRecord Query returning unexpected results, how to fix it

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this query:

```
@listings = Listing.where('city != ?', 'SommerVille')
```

I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions on what else might be causing this?

Id like to get only those listings from the DB where city !=SommerVille.

Thanks

---

EDIT
The above problems were due to leading or trailing white spaces in the city name.
So I was wondering whats the best way to query a DB where it ignores case and also ignores leading/trailing white spaces.

the following approach worked but is there a better way?

```
@unwanted_cities = Listing.where(['city != ?', "SommerVille"]).where(['city != ?', " SommerVille"]).where(['city != ?', "SommerVille "])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think most dbs support trim

```
@listings = Listing.where('TRIM(city) != ?', 'SommerVille')
```

It would be better in the long run to strip whitespace on the way in to your db

One way to ignore case, use upper

```
@listings = Listing.where('UPPER(TRIM(city)) != UPPER(?)', 'SommerVille')
```

Or

```
@listings = Listing.where('UPPER(TRIM(city)) != ?', 'SommerVille'.upcase)
```